# How to make a newly posted comment the selector in jquery (with rails)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to highlight the new message @micropost when it is posted using the second line of this code but am not having any success:

```
$("table.microposts").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'shared/feed_item', :object => @micropost)) %>"); 

$("#table.micropost_<%= @micropost.id %>").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);

$("#new_micropost")[0].reset();
```

This is the feed item partial (I tried using the div_for function to identify the new post...:

```
<tr> <%= div_for feed_item do %> 
    <td class="gravatar">
        <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %> 
    </td>
    <td class="micropost"> 
        <span class="user">
            <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %> 
        </span>
        <span class="content">
            <%= feed_item.content %>
        </span>
        <span class="timestamp">
            Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago. 
        </span>
    </td>
    <% if current_user?(feed_item.user)%>
        <td>
            <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, :method => :delete,
                                             :confirm => "You sure?",
                                             :title => feed_item.content %>
        </td>
    <% end %>   
<% end %>

</tr>

<% if @feed_items.any? %>
    <table class="microposts" summary="Status feed">
        <%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :collection => @feed_items %> 
    </table>
    <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that gives sufficient detail. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [prependTo](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) instead of [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and then do it like:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'shared/feed_item', :object => @micropost)) %>").
    prependTo($("table.microposts")).
    effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Comment: @will Sentance Is there any js error you are getting? Is the new comment/micropost added to the page?

Comment: With both versions, the new comment/micropost does add (without page reload as intended)

Comment: Do you have the jquery-ui included in the page. It should also have highlight effect included in case you have a custom build of jquery-ui. Just try `$("body").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);` in browser console or firebug to see if it works.

Comment: I get a type error back when I type that into the console (am new to the console so not sure if that might be an unrelated error on my part). Really appreciate this help by the way

Comment: Ah! Wasn't including jquery ui in the applications.html.erb. That's solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You will need the .live() function, if you add something after the page was loaded (i.e with prepend).

Have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: The selector is off, there is no need of live in this situation.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Sorry about that!